# IBM Websphere Application Server version 6.1 download for windows

Tags: java, server, websphere

I have been looking for the IBM Websphere Application Server version 6.1 at various places including IBM official website but couldn't find any options for getting the same.

I am in need of the server to run my application.

Can someone please guide me from where I can get the setup to download IBM WAS 6.1 version.

Many Thanks

Comment: WAS 6.1 is not supported for many years now. You will not find any official download any more. If you need traditional WebSphere, then download V9 for developers, but I'd strongly recommend to use [WebSphere Liberty](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/) / [Open Liberty](https://www.openliberty.io/) which is lightweight, more modern version of application server.

Answer (score 0):

You will not find any official source of 6 because it's out of date ( it was released 13 years ago ). If you want to use torrent sites, check this link :

https://tpb.party/torrent/3588433/Ibm_Websphere_Application_Server_v6.0.iso

worth trying if you need it.